# VS Code : User Snippets : on enter key press

Tags: visual-studio-code, code-snippets

I have this custom php snippet

```
    "php": {
    "prefix": "php",
    "body": [
        "<?php $1 ?>"
    ],
    "description": "php tag"
}
```

What I need to do is, when I press **Enter** at first placeholder i.e **$1**, it should add a new line with proper indent.

When I type **php** and press tab, it would do this

```
<h1><?php | ?></h1>
```

where **|** is cursor position.
I need this because sometime I use this tag inside html tags, So I want all code in single line.

But when I need php tag alone, like this

```
<?php | ?>
```

And then I press enter key, it should do this

```
<?php
    |
?>
```

Comment: It is not clear what you want to accomplish.  Can you include what your code should look like after the snippet.  Please edit your original question.

Comment: Done, please have a look.

Comment: So the real question is why doesn't vscode properly indent the next line when you hit enter.  It may be this issue, see https://github.com/Microsoft/vscode/issues/42782.  I would keep an eye on that issue and until it is resolved or verified simply make two snippets: your "inline" one and Alex's "indented".

Comment: It works fine with predefined snippets like while() {here when I hit enter} It does fine. Can't we just do the same thing with users snippets?

Answer (score 0):

```json
"body": [
    "<?php",
    "\t$1",
    "?>"
]
```

Comment: Thanks, but I already did this. I said when I hit enter then it should do Like this.

Answer (score 0):

This body `"body": [ "<?php ${1} ?>" ]` will show `<?php | ?>` on tab and afer you press enter it will be as below

```
<?php 
| ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is what I use for my divs, and it seems like it might help you here. Instead of having to hit enter to expand the tags, they are already expanded. I don't know how to get it to start together and expand only IF you hit enter, but this might help you, so I'll leave it here:

```
"wrapper div - expanded": {
    "prefix": "dd",
    "body": [
        "<div class='$1'>",
        "  $2",
        "</div>"
    ],
    "description": "creates an expanded div"
}
```

You could easily create a second snippet that is not expanded, and give it a different prefix (one d for collapsed div and two d's for an expanded div), if you want to have more control.

```
"wrapper div - collapsed": {
    "prefix": "d",
    "body": [
        "<div class='$1'>$2</div>"
    ],
    "description": "creates a collapsed div"
}
```

Comment: obviously, in your case, use php tags instead of divs haha